# How to get VS 2017 'Capability' on Build Agent

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-pipelines

I created 1 Build Agent on a pool and that worked fine. Created another one and it does not have the 'Capabilities' I need (Visual Studio, Visual Studio_15.0, MSBuild, MsBuild_15.0). How do those get added? Visual Studio Professional Update 2 is installed on 1st build agent (that works). Visual Studio 2017 Update 3 is installed on the 2nd one that does not work. I am using the same install package, but apparently MS forces update. Reinstall VS. Deleted Agent and re-added. Same. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I was just about to post a similar query, so will see if yours gets solved first. I have a library with `async Task Main(...)` which compiles fine on VS2017 update 3 on my machine. The build agent fails, despite installing VS2017 on that machine as well.

Comment: The error I am getting is "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: MSBuild version '15.0' was not found for architecture 'x86'. Verify the architecture input value is correct and verify Visual Studio 2017 is installed. MSBuild version '15.0' is included when Visual Studio 2017 is installed." I Put in a support call with MS. They confirmed that Update 3 broke ‘vswhere’ so that the agent can't find the capabilities. Hope to get it going today. Will post back later.

Comment: @Quango, Looks like the solution for me is to get Update 2 install package from MS support that does not force Update 3 upon me. Does not help you much :(

Comment: Oh well thanks anyway